# Listing All Lambda Functions using AWS SDK for Python (boto3)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to use `boto3` to get a list of all the lambdas I have in AWS. I will also need to get metrics from these lambdas (metrics are enabled in AWS console) but presently I just want to list them all. In addition, I just want to get the lambdas based on a filtered tag (ex: get all the lambdas with the tag mygroup:env=dev). This is what I have tried:

```
 import boto3

 # Create CloudWatch client
 cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch', region_name='us-west-2')
 lambdas = boto3.client('lambda', region_name='us-west-2')

 lambda_list = lambdas.list_functions(MasterRegion='us-west-2', FunctionVersion='ALL', MaxItems=123)
```

It returns the following, which essentially is an empty list of the Functions:

```
 {'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'eiopo-12mlk-12312-nm',
   'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
   'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Fri, 17 Mar 2023 19:43:00 GMT',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-length': '34',
    'connection': 'keep-alive',
    'x-amzn-requestid': 'e89098asf-123123-746b-a1d34-easd3213456'},
    'RetryAttempts': 0},
    'Functions': []
 }
```

The Lambdas are there; I can see them in my AWS Lambdas dashboard. What am I doing wrong here and how can I apply a filter for my tags?

Comment: `MasterRegion` is for Lambda@Edge functions only.

Comment: Well, that helped. It returned the functions. Now I just need to figure out how to filter by the tags.

Comment: The [list_functions()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda/client/list_functions.html) API call does not accept tags for filtering and does not return tags on the function listing. It looks like you will need to call [list_tags()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda/client/list_tags.html) on each function. Or, you might be able to use [get_resources()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/resourcegroupstaggingapi/client/get_resources.html) on the Tagging API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as [John Rotenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein) mentioned, Tagging API is better suited for this. Something like this might work

```html
import boto3

tag_key = "SOMEKEY"
tag_value = "SOMEVALUE"
client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi', region_name='ap-northeast-1')

# always good to use paginators
paginator = client.get_paginator('get_resources')

response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    TagFilters=[
        {
            'Key': tag_key,
            'Values': [
                tag_value,
            ]
        },
    ],
    ResourceTypeFilters = [
            "lambda"
        ]
)
for response in response_iterator:
    for resource in response["ResourceTagMappingList"]:
        print(resource["ResourceARN"])
```

Comment: OK, this works when I add my tag. But what if, for example, I just wanted to used a filter on a property(ex: function_name contains 'dev') and not necessarily a tag?